# anything wrong with using pyparsing

Tags: python, exception, pyparsing

i've written this to parse my own .dotf file:

```
def parseFromDOTF(file_path):
    comment = "%" + restOfLine
    typeToken = CaselessKeyword("@TYPE")
    attrToken = CaselessKeyword('@ATTRIBUTE')
    ident = Word(alphas,alphanums)
    type = Suppress(typeToken) + ident
    columnList = Group(delimitedList(nums))
    attribute = Group(Suppress(attrToken) + ident("attribute") + columnList("column"))
    DOTF = type('type') + OneOrMore(attribute)("attributes")
    DOTF.ignore(comment)
    return DOTF.parseFile(file_path)
```

below is a sample of .dotf file

```
%a comment  
@TYPE NORMAL
@ATTRIBUTE id 0
@ATTRIBUTE values 1,2,3,4
@ATTRIBUTE class 5
```

but there is something wrong with it:

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "0123456789" (at char 79), (line:3, col:15)
```

the 15th col of line 3 is a whitespace, isn't it?

so ,what's wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Is that the first four lines of the .dotf file? If so, the 3rd line 15th char is not whitespace...

Comment: oh, yes ,there is a comment line before those four lines

Comment: The `(line:3, col:15)` is `0` at the end of the `id` line, but that's not the `char 79` -- the 79th character is the `c` in `class`. So it seems to me it's expecting a digit there rather than a letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nums` equals the string `'0123456789'`.
So the definition

```
columnList = Group(delimitedList(nums))
```

tells pyparsing that a `columnList` should be a comma-delimited list of strings,
with each string literally being `'0123456789'`.

To instead match a comma-delimited list of "words" composed of characters from the string `nums`, use `Word(nums)`:

```
integer = Word(nums)
columnList = Group(delimitedList(integer))
```